# How do I fix this error on my React Native Yarn

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn start` this error is showing with error command failed with exit code. How can I solve this?

```
yarn run v1.22.18
$ node -r @babel/register ./.erb/scripts/check-port-in-use.js && yarn start:renderer
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/register'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:539:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:85:3)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:7:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
```

Comment: Do you think `@babel/runtime` _is_ installed? Give a [mre].

Comment: Your issue could be related with the package-lock file being out of sync with the package file. Try to delete that package-lock file, then run "npm install --save-dev @babel/register"